app.gitbook.com wrongly escaped the relevant link in SUMMARY.md
When I merge the commit from gitbook, I find the relevant link in SUMMARY.md is wrongly escaped because app.gitbook.com think '_' is used as a specail mark for italic.

I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem, thanks for any help.
The SUMMARY.md should not be changed, the '\' added in link will prevent gitbook-cli or honkit from generating the valid website for the book.
